# How to open a website hosted in MAMP on the Mac?

Tags: macos, mamp

I've installed MAMP on my Mac. Then, I put my website into the htdocs folder of MAMP. I started the Server. But how can I launch the website in Safari now? What's the URL to the website, when it's named "testsite" for example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it is named "**testsite.html**" then it will be at

> localhost:8888/testsite.html

Good luck with the MAMP fun that should ensue!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `localhost:8888`? See [Installing MAMP](http://sawmac.com/mamp/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

[image: mamp home]

click on the "open webstart page" then click on mywebsite on [image: my website]
mywebsite on the page.